# open another activity with a button not working

Tags: android, android-activity

So when this code runs I get no errors. It displays the buttons correctly and everything, but when I click on the button nothing happens (it just clicks and clicks and clicks nothing happens).

Below I will post the xml manifest so you can see that I have done everything perfectly, but somehow it it is not doing what I am asking it to do.

```
package com.Tripp.thebasics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jokecatagories);

        //setting up the button references
        Button jokeD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.jokeoftheday);
        Button jokeC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.jokecatagories);

        jokeD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),JokeOfTheDay.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        jokeC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent s = new Intent(".JokeCatagories");
                startActivity(s);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Tripp.thebasics"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".com.Tripp.thebasics.JokeCatagories"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.JOKECATAGORIES"     />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Sweet"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SWEET" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".com.Tripp.thebasics.JokeOfTheDay"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.JOKEOFTHEDAY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please don't shout (use ALL-CAPS) as this is not taken well on this site and can lead your question to receive down-votes or close-votes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `OnClickListeners` as follows...

```
jokeD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Menu.this, JokeOfTheDay.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});

jokeC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent s = new Intent(Menu.this, JokeCatagories.class);
        startActivity(s);
    }
});
```

Then get rid of this `<intent-filter>` from the JokeCategories `<activity>` section in the manifest...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.JOKECATAGORIES"     />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

...and get rid of this one from the JokeOfTheDay `<activity>` section...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.JOKEOFTHEDAY" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Basically, don't use the application `Context` to start an `Activity` (it's not necessary from an `Activity` as it has its own `Context`) and, on the whole, use explicit `Intents` to start `Activities` rather than defining `<intent-filter>` section in the manifest.

Comment: i get a failed to install thebasics.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with any changes I've suggested.

Comment: ok i fixed it by using the sdk version 22, but the activity still doesn't do what its programed to do i can click but nothing happens

Comment: could it have anything to do with EGL_emulation eglSurfaceAttribute not implemented? and failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR

Comment: Remove the preceding `.` from `.com.Tripp.thebasics.JokeCatagories` in the `android:name` section of the manifest. Also remove the preceding `.` from `.com.Tripp.thebasics.JokeOfTheDay`

Comment: changed it still same thing

Comment: @DevinTripp : Sorry but there's nothing in the code you posted (other than the corrections I suggested) which doesn't look out of the ordinary. I suggest you monitor logcat or try single-step debugging to try and see if there is anything in other parts of your code which might be causing problems.

Comment: could you send me a project that has this working i have made a completely new workspace, but still it didn't work could you send me a working one to my email devintripp@yahoo.com @Squonk